# BIRT two phases, Report Generation and Presentation

Tags: java, pdf-generation, reporting, birt

I am using Eclipse and Java and I wish to generate a PDF. I use BIRT but the PDF result is wrong while the web viewer is correct.

From what I understand, BIRT generates a report in the web viewer and as a PDF differently. When generating a PDF, the two phases, Report Generation and Presentation, are executed as one task and not in two tasks.

Can I force BIRT to separate the phases?

Or maybe there is a way to retrieve the "export" function in the BIRT web viewer and use it after generating the report? Meaning to generate the report and then export it.

**EDIT :** The problem is with the generation of the Table of Contents. It's fine in the web viewer but comes without page numbers in the PDF.

**EDIT 2 :** @hvb - Okay, good start. However, correct me if I'm wrong but `design` is an `IReportRunnable` that needs `engine.openReportDesign()`

I tried this : https://wiki.eclipse.org/Separate_Run_and_Render_(BIRT)_2.1

I get an error in `Platform.startup(config);`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/util/UResourceBundle
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.osgi.OSGILauncher.doStartup(OSGILauncher.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.osgi.OSGILauncher.access$0(OSGILauncher.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.osgi.OSGILauncher$1.run(OSGILauncher.java:79)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.osgi.OSGILauncher.startup(OSGILauncher.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform.startup(Platform.java:79)
    at xtensus.utils.RunTask.executeReport(RunTask.java:38)
    at xtensus.utils.RunTask.main(RunTask.java:137)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.icu.util.UResourceBundle
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: can you post the code or the URL change which you are using for `PDF` generation through `BIRT`

Comment: also which BIRT version you are using?

Comment: You should add some detail what exactly is wrong with the generated PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two phases are called "Run" and "Render".
If you call BIRT from inside Java (I mean not just call the web viewer per URL), you can decide your own what you want to use.
You either use a `RunAndRenderTask` or separate `RunTask` and `RenderTask`.

There are some minor limitations when using RunAndRenderTask. Particularly, the onPageStart event is only called once.

Code fragment for separate tasks (note the pdfOptions!):

```
            runTask = engine.createRunTask(design);
            // set parameter values...
            // runTask.setParameterValue("Parameter_Rejo_Id", rejo_id);
            runTask.run(destName + ".rptdocument");
            IReportDocument rptdoc = engine.openReportDocument(destName + ".rptdocument");
            renderTask = engine.createRenderTask(rptdoc);
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
                // Set RenderOptions and PDF RenderOptions
                IRenderOption options = new RenderOption();

                // Workaround for https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=428173

                // options.setOutputFileName(destName);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(destName);
                final int BUFSIZE = 32768;
                options.setOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFSIZE));
                options.setOutputFormat("PDF");
                PDFRenderOption pdfOptions = new PDFRenderOption(options);
                pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, IPDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_TO_MULTIPLE_PAGES);
                pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_TEXT_WRAPPING, true);
                pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_HYPHENATION, true);
                options.setOption(IRenderOption.CLOSE_OUTPUTSTREAM_ON_EXIT, true);

                renderTask.setRenderOption(options);
                renderTask.render();
```